# Decimate Selection down to a specific vertex count

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I have a vertex loop that was produced from a boolean intersection. I was wondering if there's a way, in Edit mode, to decimate the loop from the 50 vertices it is to say, 12 or so. It's not very curvy, it won't lose much shape, just a lot of unnecessary vertices.

Comment: It's a good idea to show a screenshot of your mesh. The first thing to try is to use `X` > *Limited Dissolve*.

Answer (score 1):

### Decimate Geometry

As your question's title - **Decimate Geometry** is what you're looking for. Both can find in *Blender 2.79b* and *Blender 2.80 beta*.

It collapses those selected geometry by the determined parameters, you can always redo this operator in the invoked panel to see which parameter suit for your case.

Select your target geometry in edit mode and with the **mesh** dropdown > **Clean Up** > **Decimate Geometry**

[image: Decimate Geo in Blender 2.80.53]

### What if I need a beautiful edge loop?

As another answer point out, you could create a circle with desired vertices. Move it to the edge loop you want to decimate, delete the complicated one and join the circle created. And choose both the edge loop of the opened edges, use **Bridge Edge Loops** operator to connect them.

[image: Bridge Edge Loops - B2.8]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer for your question but if you only want 12 vertices in a loop, create one, match it up with the original 50v loop (snap to vertices may help), delete your 50v loop, fill up faces to meet your need.